# Requesting password in IPython notebook

Tags: python, ssh, ipython

I have an IPython notebook which accesses data via SSH using encrypted ssh key file. I don't want to store the password in the notebook (nor in a separate file). I can use `input` in order to read the password from user prompt, but in this case the password is visible on the screen. Is there a way to securely obtaining password?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You should import the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module, then call `getpass.getpass`.

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
```

Note that in old versions, the field where you enter the password may not appear in the IPython Notebook, but instead in your terminal/command prompt window. In the latest versions of Jupyter Notebook, however, the prompt will appear in the Notebook itself.

Comment: this is constantly breaking in my experience. are there any alternatives to getpass?   

`testgetpassword = getpass("pw:")`

"/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/getpass.py:91: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal."