# using sudo inside jupyter notebook's cell

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a tutorial for a platform inside a jupyter notebook

at some point I need to run a linux command inside a cell like this :

```
!sudo apt-get install blah
```

but cant figure out how to enter the sudo pass , and I dont want to run jupyter notebook with sudo, any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update:** I checked all the methods, all of them are working.

---

**1:**

[Request password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410785/requesting-password-in-ipython-notebook) using `getpass module` which essentially hides input by user and then run [sudo command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script).

```
 import getpass
 import os

 password = getpass.getpass()
 command = "sudo -S apt-get update" #can be any command but don't forget -S as it enables input from stdin
 os.system('echo %s | %s' % (password, command))
```

**2:**

```
 import getpass
 import os

 password = getpass.getpass()
 command = "sudo -S apt-get update" # can be any command but don't forget -S as it enables input from stdin
 os.popen(command, 'w').write(password+'\n') # newline char is important otherwise prompt will wait for you to manually perform newline
```

**NOTE for above methods:**

> The field where you enter the password may not appear in the ipython
>   notebook. It appears in the terminal window on a mac, and I imagine it
>   will appear in a command shell on a PC. Even the result details would appear in the terminal.

**3:**

You can store your password in `mypasswordfile` file and just type in cell :

`!sudo -S apt-get install blah < /pathto/mypasswordfile # again -S is important here`

I would prefer this method if I want to view output of the command in jupyter notebook itself.

**References:**

1. [Requesting password in IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410785/requesting-password-in-ipython-notebook)
2. https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html
3. [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Comment: Is there a variation on the above which doesn't leave the password accessible if you step away from the notebook?

Answer (score 8):

I want to point another possibility for the case where jupyter is running on localhost: instead of **sudo**, use **[pkexec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pkexec.1.html)** (or for older systems **[gksu](http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/)**):

```
!pkexec apt-get install blah
```

This will ask for the password in a gui solving the problem...

Comment: The best answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass python variables from a notebook to the shell without importing the `os` or `subprocess` modules by using the {varname} syntax (e.g. [this cool blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html)).

If you have defined a password and command variable in python (see Suparshva's answer) then you can run this one-liner:

```
!echo {password}|sudo -S {command}
```

The exclamation mark tells jupyter to run it in the shell, the `echo` command will then get the real password (e.g. 'funkymonkey') from the variable called `password` and then pipe it into the sudo'd `command` variable (which is a string that describes a shell command, e.g. 'apt-get update').

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your password to be stored somewhere, you could write:

```
from getpass import getpass
!echo {getpass()} | sudo -S {command}
```

P.S. this also answers Ian Danforth's question

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
subprocess.Pope(['sudo', 'apt-get', 'install', 'bla'])
```

If you want to avoid the python syntax, you can define your own cell magic that does that for you (e.g. `%sudo apt-get install bla`).

Comment: You mean `Popen`; but really, like its documentation already tells you, prefer `subprocess.run` in scenarios where you simply want to run an external process and wait for it to finish.

Comment: Anyway, this does nothing to provide the password to `sudo`