# Python Jupyter Notebook how can I list the /root directory.

Tags: python-2.7, list, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I can list the root directory using a script file and command line.

```
%%writefile ShowDir.py
import os
import sys
from sys import argv
DIR = argv[1]
show = os.listdir(DIR)
print show
```

Then I ran in the terminal:
!echo mypassword | sudo -S python ShowDir.py /root
It worked, but I want a more graceful approach.
I also tried:
This will run files, make directories, remove files directories, but for some reason will not LIST them.

```
import os, subprocess
ret = subprocess.check_call("echo mypassword | sudo -S ls /root",   shell=True) 
ret
```

It just returned a 0, no directory listing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using sudo inside jupyter notebook's cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996933/using-sudo-inside-jupyter-notebooks-cell)

Comment: No, It is not. I can use sudo in a Jupyter Notebook all the time.  I even showed an example. But, for some reason, it will not list the files in /root . Try to list files with the same command for example " ls /root/ " , does not work. I used the password.password() and am familiar with it. Listing directories does not work.