# How to input password to a shell command 'git push' from a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, linux, shell, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in a Jupyter Notebook's cell:

```
!git push origin master
```

which will ask my password for Github but the cell keeps on running as I can't find the way to input my password. For some reason, I want to push the code this way.

I tried to follow the [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996933/using-sudo-inside-jupyter-notebooks-cell) but nothing seems to be working in my case. Here's what I tried and it didn't work:

```
import getpass
import os

password = getpass.getpass()
command = "git -S push origin master " #can be any command but don't forget -S as it enables input from stdin
os.system('echo %s | %s' % (password, command))
```

Here's the log for above:

```
unknown option: -S
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-S` is an option of `sudo`, not `git`... as you can see `git` is not even asking for password it just tells you that `-S` is invalid.

I believe `git` uses a secure way to get the password, reading from the `tty` and not stdin. It's probably quite hard to get a hand on the correct `tty` to input that password to make this work. Moreover this means that you have to write the password in plaintext in your notebook.

The correct way to handle this is to:

- Generate an `ssh` key using `ssh-keygen` *without a passphrase*
- Configure your server to use that key
- Configure `git` to use the SSH protocol to do the `push`

This completely avoids a request for passwords.

Comment: Okay, writing in plain text will work also but how can I do that? Passing the password as string to `echo %s | %s` that also doesn't work. I will try ssh though.

Comment: @FaizanAli I will not provide any information about that, since other people may think it is a good idea, which is not. One solution is to modify the repository configuration to use the `repo` HTTPS url with credentials in it. Again this avoids any password prompt but you have the credentials in plaintext in your repository configuration. Check [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/815043/how-to-give-username-password-to-git-clone-in-a-script-but-not-store-credential) for some more information. Obviously you can change this configuration from the notebook...

Comment: I found my solution using access tokens through that ServerFault question, thanks for that.